# Send extra information over socket connection

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have the following code to send image information over a socket connection from an Android device to a server PC. How can I send along with the image data a Point object which corresponds to a position the user is pressing on the screen which I already know?

```
YuvImage yuv_image = new YuvImage(imageDataArray, 
ImageFormat.NV21,
previewWidth,
previewHeight, null);
final ByteArrayOutputStream output_stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, previewWidth, previewHeight);
yuv_image.compressToJpeg(rect, 75, output_stream);

Point p = point;
byte[] array = output_stream.toByteArray();

InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
out.write(array);
//Here I would also like to to send the point (p) across, Could even send it as 2 integer values.
```

Is there anyway to send a TAG with the data so I can differentiate on the side of the server?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a message class which is serializable and contains both a point and an image and send it instead of two objects.